# Nodejs Sequelize cli wont change environment

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize-cli

I'm having problems trying to change my database environment using Sequelize Cli.

I was able to configure migrations and database access without problem but when i run my migration it only apply to development, even if i change the NODE_ENV variable in my .env it wont matter, development is still used

My models/index.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').config()

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
```

My .env:

```
NODE_ENV='test' # development | test | production
```

And my config/config.json:

```
{
  "test": {
    "username": "teste",
    "password": "123123123",
    "database": "question_test",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "development": {
    "username": "teste",
    "password": "123123123",
    "database": "question_development",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "teste",
    "password": "123123123",
    "database": "question_production",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Even if i change my const env to `const env = 'test'` development env is choosen

```
# npx sequelize-cli db:migrate            

Sequelize CLI [Node: 16.9.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.5]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20210922174741-create-question: migrating =======
== 20210922174741-create-question: migrated (0.190s)
```

I cant see what im doing wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: For those with the same problem i found a work around,

The user KarlMacz came with a solution for this problem posted on GitHub that worked for me and i hope it helps anyone in the future

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/835#issuecomment-881912943

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify on which env you're working on (`--env yourEnvName`),
use this command, it worked with me.

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env test
```